# Session stored items per page in document and media liferay portlet

Tags: session, liferay, media, documents

I'm using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

I want to have items per page displayed in Documents and Media portlet stored in user session. I tried to change view_file_entries.jspf and view.jsp in ../document_library_display/, which I belive are the files that handles this view, but with no luck.

Can somebody guide me where to do it? I know how.

Answer (score 0):

`Documents and Media` and `Document and Media Display` are two separate portlets.

So if you want to change for `Documents & Media` then you would have to change JSPs in `/html/portlet/document_library/` and the JSPs that would be of help would be `view_entries.jsp` and `init.jsp`.

Another suggestion, you can even think about storing the items/page as User preference instead of User session.

We might be able to help more if you show us some code and elaborate more on your question.

Comment: I meant Document and Media Display I belive. One in control panel, where You are browsing files.

Comment: In the control-panel there is only `Document & Media`, the display portlet is an instanceable portlet to be put on various pages. The JSPs in DM portlet are reused for control-panel, essentially its the same portlet.

Comment: So should I now include this two jsp from basic Liferay 6.1.0 GA1?

Comment: Yes you can try with that.